# Webhook support for GitLab application

Tags: oauth, gitlab, webhooks

I am looking for general information on GitLab, specifically OAuth applications and Webhook

I have created my own application and I can register it with GitLab. However, as part of my application I also want to be able to receive webhooks when any events happen in the repo - specifically push events.

I can register webhooks separately from the Project -> Settings -> Webhooks menu. But my goal is that when users authorize the application, the webhook is automatically registered on their repositories.

Is there a way to do this? One thought I had was to register the webhooks using the GitLab API once the user completes the OAuth workflow, but I am yet to try it out.

Comment: it might be worth pointing out, that you can also do webhooks on a group level. if that is feasible in your case